# Nginx multiple listeners (with php application)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, virtualbox

I want Nginx to serve both my jenkins server and my Laravel (php) application. Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {

                proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
                proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;

                proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8081 https://jenkins.domain.tld;
        }
}

server {
    listen 9000;
    listen [::]:9000;

    root /var/www/my-app/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name my-app.io;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I am using virtual-box as my virtual machine emulator for ubuntu 14. I am able to access jenkins application by going to `http://127.0.0.1:8081` (I have changed the jenkins default port).
But when I am trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:9000` I am getting an error, I have checked Ngnix logs but couldn't find any information regarding a request to port 9000.
Also I have made port forwarding in virtual-box, here is a screenshot:
[image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: Edit `/etc/hosts` file, add `my-app.io 127.0.0.1` and then use `http://my-app.io:9000`. You can access `http://127.0.0.1:8081` because you marked it as `default_server` in the config.

Comment: Should I do this on my machine or on the virtual machine?

Comment: I thought you used your VM to access the service. Do you use windows as host machine or linux? If you use windows machine to access your VM, find out what the IP of your VM is via `ifconfig` (look for inet addr). Edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and add the same line i showed you, just replace 127.0.0.1 with the IP of your VM.

Comment: I am using mac as my dev machine and running vm on it. And I am trying to mimc a prod machine on the vm (which runs ubuntu server)

Comment: Ah, ok, then edit `/etc/hosts` file on your mac machine, instead of `127.0.0.1` specify the IP of your VM.

Comment: mmm I am struggling with finding the vm address, here is my output after running  ifconfig on my mac: http://prntscr.com/b6rgxd

Comment: You run ifconfig on your VM, not on your mac. You want your VM to tell you what its assigned IP is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112584/discussion-between-vlio20-and-n-b).

Answer (score 0):

Use server_name localhost too for php.

Comment: Also add default_server

Comment: can I have multiple default servers?